# Using BYTEDICT compression with VARCHAR columns in Redshift: can someone please clarify this statement from the docs?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm reading through the [AWS Redshift documentation regarding compression types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html). In the section on [BYTEDICT compression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Byte_dictionary_encoding.html) it says the following:

> Byte-dictionary encoding is not always effective when used with
>   VARCHAR columns. Using BYTEDICT with large VARCHAR columns might cause
>   excessive disk usage. We strongly recommend using a different
>   encoding, such as LZO, for VARCHAR columns.

Assuming that "large VARCHAR columns" means "high cardinality," that recommendation makes sense. However, the last sentence seems to say one shouldn't bother using `BYTEDICT` with `VARCHAR` *at all*. That doesn't make sense to me though. **If you had millions of `VARCHAR` rows, but the cardinality was low (e.g. Canadian Provinces), wouldn't `BYTEDICT` be the best choice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important word here is "always", meaning that sometimes it is and sometimes it is not the best option.

"Byte-dictionary encoding is not **always** effective when used with VARCHAR columns"

Bytedict works fine in the use case that you have set out of course, that is what it is there for!

If this is important to your use case then you must try out the options both for storage and query performance.

Comment: Right, if it weren't for that last sentence I wouldn't have thought much more about it. But that last sentence in the documentation excerpt is what made me think there was some unstated reason for not using a `BYTEDICT`. You know how you hear people "strongly recommend" not holding lit firecrackers? In reference to the bolded part of my question statement, would you use a `BYTEDICT` in that situation?

Comment: Yes I would - at least give it a try with some data! However In many cases (in my experience with Redshift) that kind of detailed (fine grained) optimisation makes little or no difference.

Comment: Besides storage savings, you can get big query performance boosts on scenarios like the one you mentioned. Be sure to test, though! [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/amazon-redshift-string-query-performance-up-to-63x/)

Comment: Yes Gabe, interesting. Things have moved on a little in the 4 years since i posted the answer :)